# Git how to sort files based on number of authors

Tags: git

In the Git history, how to sort the files which have more number of authors in the last 1 year.

I have used the below command to list all the authors and their commit count for the file.

```
git blame --line-porcelain $i | sed -n 's/author //p' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
```

But I need to list files which has more number of author and not more number of commit by the same person.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used below command to get list of files and their author.

```
git blame --line-porcelain --since "1 year" $i | sed -n 's/author //p' | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn|wc -l
```

Answer (score 0):

To list all commits in your repo since one year, you can use `git log` :

```
git log --all --since "1 year"
```

You can use the `--format` option to customize the message printed for each commit :`%ae` will print the email of each commit's author, `%an` will print the authors' names ;
`--name-only` will list the files modified in each commit :

```
git log --all --since "1 year" --format="author:%ae" --name-only
```

You can now write a script, which scans the output of this command, and computes the number of different authors who modified each individual file.